# Objective-C++ Calling C or C++ function

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, objective-c++

as most of the other Objective-C questions posted here, I too am a newbie to ObjC.

I am writing an iOS application based on our existing product that is written in C# and C++.

I have written an entire library in C++, that I was hoping to use directly in the iOS device, by simply providing a few #ifdef's to block the code where necessary.  For example, I have an entire C++ class for making HTTP requests using Winsock.  So, in order to be able to convert this portion of the API to Obj-C, I was hoping I could write some simple Obj-C classes for sending, and receiving data over the built in Libraries for iOS, using NSURL, NSStrings, etc.

But, I seem to not be able to pass things INTO an Obj-C(++) method, that I've written in C++.  And I wanted to find out here, for sure, if this is even possible before I burn too many hours on a lost cause.

It is my understanding, by the way Obj-C was built/designed, that pretty much IS in fact all C code behind the scenes, so merging the two languages is not difficult.

Am I wrong here?  Can I, for example, do something like this:

```
class NameValueCollection {
  NameValueCollection() { };
  NameValueCollection(std::string key, std::string value);
  ~NameValueCollection();
...
};
```

Then, say, in Obj-C (Obj-C++ actually, I've already changed the language the files are compiled to...)

```
-(BOOL)initWithValues:(NameValueCollection*) nvc result:(NSString*)result;
```

Am I WAY out of line trying to do this?  And if so, then is it possible to do one of the two alternates?

Calling an ObjC++ method from within a C++ class/object/method, OR, calling a C++ method inside of an Obj-C++ method?

I have to admit that I kind of assumed the last alternane would work, and I was PRETTY sure the first alternate would work, but it would be BEST if the first option was possible.  Can anyone provide good insight to this, and even if I'm taking the correct approach by attempting this in Obj-C++, or would this only be possible in Obj-C, calling C functions, instead of C++ methods so I could use our predefined, (and pre-debugged) objects RIGHT in the iOS application, just substituting Obj-C++ code where the rubber meets the proverbial road...

I am the original author of the C++ library code, so I COULD in fact make changes to it, if necessary, or even use the Pre-Processor to my advantage, but obviously the less code I have to change on the C++ side, the *MUCH* better!  :)  I am NOT building the C++ code into a Dynlib, or anything like that, I'm simply sharing the files between projects at the source control level.  But, I am open to any ideas that will make this whole thing work the way I'm attempting to.

Thanks in advance guys...

Comment: What's not working?  You can call plain C/C++ functions from Objective-C just fine.

Comment: You just have to remember to make the "glue" modules ".mm".

Comment: What you've written should work fine.  Note that to use C++ code, you need to use a `.mm` extension to signify the file is an Objective-C++ file.  However, it should be noted that Winsock calls aren't going to work - they would need to be #ifdef'd out and replaced with standard Unix sockets calls, or higher-level native networking API's.

Comment: The two biggies, I've found are: (1) for non-POD classes, you should wrap them in a structure, and pass the structure as an opaque type, and (2) handle **all** exceptions at the boundary.  Don't let Objective-C exceptions pass into C++, and don't let C++ exceptions pass into Objective-C.  Objective-C++ lets you kind of mix the two, but I only use it as a very thin interface.

Comment: Adam and sfstewman, I +1'd your comment because you were right...  Now that I'm much more experienced in ObjC++ I know the things to look out for, etc.  Perhaps the biggest thing I learned is that C linkage that has to be used.  So now, my cross-platform library sources all include an #ifdef that extern "C"'s my .h files if we are compiling in Obj-C, whatever the case may be.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is definitely possible to use c++ classes/methods within obj-c++. I've been doing some iOS development using the BulletPhysics library, which is c++, and I can use its functionality without any problems. The thing I think you need to do is add your library's source files to you project. With BulletPhysics, compiling the library externally as a framework and then importing the framework didn't work correctly for me. So what i did was add the source files of the library to the project, then just #include the headers that i needed and then xcode took care of compiling the library and my source code, and then it worked.

Just make sure you are using .mm for the extension of the files that are using the library headers.